# How to make gain margin 6dB

Tags: gain

So I have a non-inverting opamp configuration R1=20k and the system starts to oscillate if R2 is less than 20k. I need to make the gain margin equal to 6dB by choosing the right value for R2.[image: Circuit]

Comment: Um, oscillations without any capacitive or inductive components is... unexpected, unless you have a very specific input signal. What's attached to Viz, what signal do you feed in at Vul, what type of opamp specifically are you using, and how do you supply power to Vcc/Vee?

Comment: Vcc and Vee don't play a role and the oscillations occur because of the pole of the opamp but it's not a real opamp so can't help you there.

Comment: I kind of think that the solution could be R2=30k because the system is unstable if the amplification is less than 2 and a 6dB gain margin is 2 so I think that a 4x amplification should be the right answer but I am not sure.

Comment: So, what Opamp (model) are you using? Idealized opamps don't start to oscillate by themselves. You're not giving us all info. If you have a model with a specific phase response, well, therein lies your answer.

Comment: There are opamps which are uncompensated or partly compensated - and, as a consequence, they are instable for heavy feedback (small closed-loop gains). Hence, we must know which type you are using - otherwise no answer is possible. Or perhaps you are using a transimpedance type (current-feedback amplifier)? In this case, the feedback resistance must not fall below a specified value - independent on the closed-loop gain.

Comment: That's all the information that is given.

Comment: In this case, an answer is impossible because the tendency to oscillate is determined by the frequency-dependent open-loop gain characteristic of the opamp only!!

Comment: I suspect this is homework question and OP is supposed to calculate absolute gain and convert it to dB Gain. In this case, absolute gain would be R2/R1 and dB gain would be $ 20log_{10}(R2/R1) /$

Comment: If I got it right in my previous comment then 4x amplification would be correct answer as you suspected and thus R2=80k Ohm would be correct.

Comment: yes but this is a non-inverting opamp configuration so the gain is R2/R1+1

Comment: That means that R2=(4-1)*R1 is that right?

Comment: I don`t think that the task is related to a closed-loop gain. The tendency to oscillate is mentioned explicitely!

Comment: Sorry I was in hurry and mistakenly thought of it as INV config, in that case you're right but check answer and other comments as oscillations have been explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a circuit with gain of +0.1 ( -20dB gain, but **INPHASE**) and the opamp has rolloff well below Unity Gain Bandwidth. What to do?

try this compensation approach: make the noise gain 6dB higher (or even more, if you need) at very high frequencies, using a series RC from virtual-ground to Ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDXMdl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That works too by phase lead-lag compensation with R2/R3=2 but question is on R2 value, which for Non-Inverting input Av=2x(1+1)=4= 1x(3+1) thus R2=becomes 3x the value or 3x20k=60k

Comment: There is no need to use a model because we already have the amplification at which the system is critically stable so just by multiplying this amplification by the desired gain margin we get to the new value for R2=(GM*Ap-1)*R1=(2*2-1)*20k=60k Ap is the critically stable amplification when R2=20k and GM =10^(6/20). But this is also helpful for simulating purposes so thanks.